# 3party jQuery Library is loaded before jQuery

Tags: magento2, jquery

I have a custom module that does only one thing and that is lazy loading images.
For the lazy loading part, I'm using jQuery Lazy (http://jquery.eisbehr.de/lazy/)

My Problem: 
Sometimes the jQuery Lazy loading library is loaded BEFORE jQuery which results in console errors.

Hereunder my code:

requirejs-config.js:

```
var config = {
   map: {
    '*': {
        jqlazy: 'Fks_Custom/js/jquery.lazy.min',
        }
   },
   shim: {
      jqlazy: {
          deps: ['jquery']
      }
   }
};
```

Template; lazyload.phtml:

```
 <script>

 require([
    "jquery",
    'jqlazy'
    ], function($) {

    $(".lazy").Lazy({
        enableThrottle: true,
        throttle: 250
    });

});

</script>
```

Is there something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your `.phtml` template:

```
<script>

 require([
    "jquery",
    'jqlazy'
    ], function($) {

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".lazy").Lazy({
        enableThrottle: true,
        throttle: 250
    });
 });
});

</script>
```